# I am iterating the Mongodb Collection with Java for loop which is creating heap Memory issue

Tags: java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/id/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getClaimsDetailById(@RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "id") String id) throws JsonProcessingException {
    MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(this.collection);
    List claim = new ArrayList();
    Document document = new Document("_id", new ObjectId(id));
    List<Document> claims = collection.find(document).into(claim);
    List<Document> claimsUpdatedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Document doc : claims) {
        if (null != doc.get("Common")) {
            Document common = (Document) doc.get("Common");
            if (null != common.get("EffectiveDate")) {
                Date date = (Date) common.get("EffectiveDate");
                common.put("EffectiveDate",convertDate(date));
            }
            if (null != common.get("ExpirationDate")) {
                Date date = (Date) common.get("ExpirationDate");
                common.put("ExpirationDate",convertDate(date));
            }
            doc.put("Common",common);
            claimsUpdatedList.add(doc);
        }
    }
    JsonWriterSettings writerSettings = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.SHELL).indent(true).build();
    return claimsUpdatedList.get(0).toJson(writerSettings);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code. However, a code dump is not a good question. Please [edit] your question and describe in plain English what problem you have. What is the memory issue? Do you have a stack trace to include? See also [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `into()`, which loads all the data at once into the `List`, therefore possibly overloading the heap if the data is very large.

Instead, you should be using `iterator()`, which uses the database cursor to process the data one-by-one, without loading them into application memory. This concept is not restricted to Mongo, it is a common mechanism with all databases (which is why the very concept of cursors exists).

For example:

```
...
FindIterable<Document> documentCursor = collection.find(document);
for (Document doc : documentCursor) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you valuable suggestion .Could you show one scenario as I am new to Mongodb

Comment: Added a sample modification to your code in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your response .It helped me .